# Is this possible with accordions to keep all sections close untill user clicked on particular section header

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Is this possible with accordions to  keep all sections close until user click on particular section header.i tried but by default, accordions always keep one section open.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may specify [`active: false`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) in accordion options.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gRB94/)

Comment: Hi David,I tried your demo code and it is working and very easy to understand....thanks a lot...

Comment: Good stuff David, I actually didn't know about the accordian method in jQuery. Upvote!

EDIT: I see that this is jQuery UI. Still cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8N4ZQ/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});​
```